# Find the Taylor series and prove it converges using the definition

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

I'm studying for the FE Exam. A simple walk-through would be appreciated to help my understanding of how to solve similar problems.

Find the Taylor series about $x=2$ for the function

$f(x) = x^5 - 3x^4 + 2x^3 - x^2 - x + 1 $

And prove that the Taylor series converges to $f$ using the definition.

Comment: Do you know what is the definition of taylor series of a class $C^\infty$ function?

Comment: I know the Taylor Series definition sum from n=0 to inf of nth-derivitive of f(c) over n! all times (x-a)^n

Answer (score 1):

As $f^{(k)}=0$ for $k>5$, the Taylor series is a finite sum and $=f$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

As answered by Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla, you just need to focus on the first six terms. You can apply the standard method computing the values of the function and the first fifth derivatives or replace in your expression $x$ by $(t+2)$ and expand. Doing so, you will arrive to $$t^5+7 t^4+18 t^3+19 t^2+3 t-5$$ that is to say that $$f(x) = -5+3 (x-2)+19 (x-2)^2+18 (x-2)^3+7 (x-2)^4+(x-2)^5$$